# Cannot change the name of firebase database

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to build a web app with Firebase using this tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-get-to-know-web?continue=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Flearn%2Fpathways%2Ffirebase-web%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fcodelabs%2Ffirebase-get-to-know-web#0

In step 7, I try to change the name of the database from "guestbook" to "guest" (addDoc(collection(db, 'guestbook') => addDoc(collection(db, 'guest')) but then it didn't work. The error is 'Missing or insufficient permission').

Anyone here know why? I thought changing the name of the database doesn't matter.

Comment: You are not changing database. You are changing collection name where you try to write data. When did you create this database? By default, in production mode database rules allow to read/write operations to database only to a date around one month.

Comment: Firebase collection names are immutable see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251826/updating-a-collection-name-in-cloud-firestore). Secondly, `addDoc` doesn't change the name of anything - it adds a document hence the function name call - in this case it would add a new collection 'guest'. See the documentation [Add Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#add_data) for an example. Lastly, you're probably not authenticated, which is what's throwing the error. (Or your rules are set up to not allow your current auth'd user write access). Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have set up Firebase security rules (in step 9 of the tutorial). You'll need to change `guestbook` to `guest` in those rules as well.

Those rules control whether clients are allowed to read or change data in firestore. If a collection isn't mentioned in the rules, the default is to deny all read and write requests.